# Configuring DbContext Constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use EF Core tools to manage an SqlServer database I'm designing in a C# class library. It's in a class library because I need to use the database schema in both an MVC6 website and some command line tools.

I had to convert the class library to being a netapp because the current version of the tooling doesn't support class libraries, but I don't think that's the source of my problem.

My DbContext class looks like this:

```
public class ConnellDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ConnellUser>
{
    public ConnellDbContext( DbContextOptions<ConnellDbContext> options )
    {
    }

    // core tables
    public DbSet<Ballot> Ballots { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

When I run "dotnet ef migrations list" on the Package Manager Console, I get the following error message:

> No parameterless constructor was found on 'ConnellDbContext'. Either
>   add a parameterless constructor to 'ConnellDbContext' or add an
>   implementation of  'IDbContextFactory' in the same
>   assembly as 'ConnellDbContext'.

I'm not quite sure how to resolve this. It's easy enough to insert a parameterless constructor, but when I do I get the following error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
>   passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I >>think<< this means the console commands are not picking up the connection string information in my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-ConnellCampaigns;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;AttachDbFilename=e:\\SqlServer\\Data\\ConnellCampaigns.mdf;"
  }
}
```

I'm missing something about how the EF tooling accesses the source code to do its magic. Any pointers or leads would be much appreciated.

**Additional Info**

Thanx to Mr. Anderson I've made a bit of progress. I added a parameterless constructor and overrode the OnConfiguring() method in my DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring( DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder )
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true );

    IConfigurationRoot config = builder.Build();

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") );
}
```

That didn't work, but explicitly including the actual connection string in the call to UseSqlServer() did. Thoughts on why the call based on "DefaultConnection" didn't work?

Comment: There is no such magic. EF employs the singleton model, with a static instance of DbContext<T> for every T. In order to create the instance, however, it needs parameterless ctor.

Comment: But then why is it gacking when I add such a ctor?

Comment: It looks like EF does not know which db connection to bind your context to. Did you try overriding `OnConfiguring()` in `ConnellDbContext`?

Comment: No, I didn't try that. The docs I read, to the extent I understood them, seemed to say that providing either a parameterless ctor or overriding OnConfiguring() would work. The former seemed easier. But I don't think I've got the parameterless ctor set up correctly (it's just an empty method at this point).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConnellDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ConnellUser>
{
    internal static string connection_string
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    public ConnellDbContext() : base(connection_string)
    {

    }
    // core tables
    public DbSet<Ballot> Ballots { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Comment: And where does `connection_string` come from?

Comment: @JohnyL you can create property which reads the connection string from the config. let me edit my answer for the same.

Comment: @JohnyL makes sense now?

Comment: First, this is EF Core - the connection string must be used in `OnConfiguring` method. Second, forgetting the first point, how will you pass connection string? Your `ConnellDbContext`'s constructor does not receive connection string - it has nothing to pass to `base`.

Comment: @JohnyL you are right! it is diff when it comes to .Net Core.

Comment: honestly if this is EF Core I wouldn't have any mention of conn strings anywhere, no `OnConfiguring` either.  everything will be injected in via DI (including conn details)