# DbContext Has No Connection String

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm building an MVC application, using LinqPad6 for testing. As the application tries to configure the controller, I get an error that DbContext doesn't have a connection string. Here's an image:

[image]

Here's part of my TimeCardsContext code:

public partial class TimeCardsContext : DbContext
{
public readonly string _connectionString;
public virtual DbSet TimeCards { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet Workers { get; set; }

```
    public TimeCardsContext(DbContextOptions<TimeCardsContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        _connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("TimeConnect");
    }
```

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            if(!options.IsConfigured)
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
            }
        }
```

So, where's the missing connection string? I set a breakpoint In the context class so I could check the connection string, but the debugger never hits it. So, I'm at a complete  loss.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're doing in this Linqpad query. There are several ways to use an EF context in Linqpad. How did you do that?

Comment: this solution might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808604/configuring-dbcontext-constructor?rq=1

Comment: Gert, I've used LinqPad for many years to test data functions in a VS application. From a query window, simply press F4, and you have the option to include your project's dll. You can then use LinqPad to exercise the data functions. I like it because it gives better, or easier to see, error messages.

Comment: The link Abi included gave me enough different perspective to find a solution. I'd mark that as the Answer,  if I could.

Comment: Still, that's only one way of using it. And we can't see how you instantiate and initialize the context in the Linqpad query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing external options via the DbContext constructor. Inside your `OnConfiguring` override, you're specifically checking if options have been configured.

The reason your connection string is null is being it's likely being passed over.

From the MSDN Documentation on [DbContextOptionsBuilder.IsConfigured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.isconfigured?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder_IsConfigured)

> Gets a value indicating whether any options have been configured. This can be useful when you have overridden OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder) to configure the context, but in some cases you also externally provide options via the context constructor. This property can be used to determine if the options have already been set, and skip some or all of the logic in OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder).

Either pass your connection string via the constructor options, or remove the IsConfigured check.

Comment: The link provided information on the IsConfigured test, but removing the IsConfigured test fixed that particular problem.